# Javascript Ajax Get

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I am trying to get javascript to load and refresh live data. But i can't get it to show any of the data.

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 </head>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function updateStats() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost/data.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sysstats').html(data.sysstats);
            $('#aststats').html(data.aststats);
            scheduleStatsUpdate();
        },
        error: updateFailed
    });
}
function scheduleStatsUpdate() {
    stats_timer = setTimeout('updateStats();',6000);
}
</script>

<body>


<div id="aststats" class="infobox ui-widget-content  ui-corner-all">

</div>
<div id="sysstats" class="infobox ui-widget-content  ui-corner-all">

</div>
</body>
```

The Data.php file returns these contents:

```
{"sysstats":"<h3 class=\"ui-widget-header  ui-state-default ui-corner-all\">System Statistics<\/h3><h4>Processor<\/h4><div class=\"databox\" style=\"width:200px;\">\n <div class=\"dataname\">Load Average<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\"><a href=\"#\" title=\"Load Average: 0.01\">0.01<\/a><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"CPU: 0.00 \/ 100 (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">CPU<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<h4>Memory<\/h4><div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"App Memory: 527.67MB \/ 2010.453125MB (26%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:52px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">App Memory<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">26%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"Swap: 0.00MB \/ 760.8828125MB (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">Swap<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<h4>Disks<\/h4><div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"\/: 2.53GB \/ 30.18GB (8%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:16px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">\/<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">8%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"\/boot: 0.01GB \/ 0.10GB (10%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:20px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">\/boot<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">10%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:200px;\" title=\"\/dev\/shm: 0.00GB \/ 0.98GB (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">\/dev\/shm<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0%<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<h4>Networks<\/h4><div class=\"databox\" style=\"width:200px;\">\n <div class=\"dataname\">eth0 receive<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\"><a href=\"#\" title=\"eth0 receive: 0.00 KB\/s\">0.00 KB\/s<\/a><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox\" style=\"width:200px;\">\n <div class=\"dataname\">eth0 transmit<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\"><a href=\"#\" title=\"eth0 transmit: 0.00 KB\/s\">0.00 KB\/s<\/a><\/div>\n<\/div>\n","aststats":"<h3 class=\"ui-widget-header  ui-state-default ui-corner-all\">FreePBX Statistics<\/h3><div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:400px;\" title=\"Total active calls: 0 \/ 18 (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">Total active calls<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:400px;\" title=\"Internal calls: 0 \/ 18 (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">Internal calls<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:400px;\" title=\"External calls: 0 \/ 18 (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">External calls<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"databox graphbox\" style=\"width:400px;\" title=\"Total active channels: 0 \/ 36 (0%)\">\n <div class=\"bargraph graphok\" style=\"width:0px;\"><\/div>\n <div class=\"dataname\">Total active channels<\/div>\n <div class=\"datavalue\">0<\/div>\n<\/div>\n<h4>FreePBX Connections<\/h4>"}
```

I can't get it to even show the data. Do I need anything special install on my server to run this code?

Comment: Where are you calling `updateStats()` initially?

Comment: Try using firebug to see if you really are sending and receiving the data properly.

Comment: I tried calling it with `<body onload="updateStats()">` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Check in the console to see if you're getting the data - http://jsfiddle.net/946XL/ injecting the data into it and skipping the AJAX works just fine

Comment: The console is blank when the page loads.

Comment: You tried with `onload` within the body tag, but what are you using now? If you are not calling the function then you are not going to get any data. Also can you go directly to the data.php file in the browser? If that doesn't return data then that is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function that starts your ajax call or timeout, but I think you want to run:

```
     setInterval(function() {
       updateStats();
     }, 6000);
```

instead.

Comment: I have tried `window.onload = function updateStats() {}` just try and get the data but I am not getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're calling to $('#sysstats').html(data.sysstats); ? ....I think you don't have any element with the "sysstats" id...instead, you have "aststats" or "sysinfo" id's....

Comment: That was a typo but it still doesn't work. aststats and sysstats should load, but they both don't.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
function scheduleStatsUpdate() {
   stats_timer = setTimeout('updateStats();',6000);
}
```

by

```
(function scheduleStatsUpdate() {
  stats_timer = setTimeout('updateStats();',6000);
})();
```